# Reload column names in ActiveRecord model class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, scripting, schema

I have a script using ActiveRecord that creates column names dynamically based on values read from a CSV file, something like this:

```
FasterCSV.foreach('votes.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
  column_name = "roll_call_id_#{row['roll_call_id']}"

  if !Legislator.columns.map(&:name).include?(column_name)
    connection_pool.connection.add_column('legislators', column_name, 'string')
  end
end
```

The problem is that, after creating the new column, I can't do a `legislator.update_attribute(column_name, value)` because the class doesn't pick up the new column and complains it doesn't exist.

How can I make it query the table structure again?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`Legislator.reset_column_information` ([API info](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/reset_column_information/class))

Comment: Is there a simple way to apply to every model, eg: `ActiveRecord::Base. reset_column_information` ?

Comment: Yep, `ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.each(&:reset_column_information)`

Answer (score 0):

as obvio171 pointed out, it's quite easy:

You need to create a bare model class upfront.

Then in the migration you need to call MyModel.reset_column_information,
so that the column information is reloaded so that is up with the new table you just created (or changed)

You can then use just every method to create new records.

I use something like:

```
data = [[1,'foo'], [2,'bar'],[3,'zip']].map{|a,b| {id:a, txt:b} }
MyModel.create!(data)
```

But if your seed data is more than a few constants,
then you should probably not burry your data into a migration like this.